# TypeScript types based on capitalization of a key

Tags: typescript, template-literals, mapped-types

Trying to add types to an existing JS library I'm using. The library unfortunately has a rule that the type of the value in an object is somewhat determined by the capitalization of the first letter of its associated key. I thought something like the below might work, but it does not.

```
type UppercaseLetters = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'H' | 'I' | 'J' | 'K' | 'L' | 'M' | 'N' | 'O' | 'P' | 'Q' | 'R' | 'S' | 'T' | 'U' | 'V' | 'W' | 'X' | 'Y' | 'Z';
type LowercaseLetters = Lowercase<UppercaseLetters>;

type RefKey = `${UppercaseLetters}${string}`
type PropKey = `${LowercaseLetters}${string}`

// Define these types just so it compiles
type SomeRefType = number;
type SomePropType = boolean;

type Spec = {
  type: string
} & {
  [s in RefKey]: SomeRefType
} & {
  [s in PropKey]: SomePropType
};
```

This compiles, but the actual type that `Spec` becomes is:

```
type Spec = {
    type: string;
} & {} & {}
```

Any ideas out there? Perhaps this case is just too out of the left field for TypeScript to handle.

Example object:

```
const specObj: Spec = {
  type: 'Some string',
  Apple: 3,
  Orange: 6,
  lowerCaseKey: false,
  anotherOne: true
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of an object ?

Comment: Where does the `${string}` come from in line 4 and 5?

Comment: @Tino I think it's a placeholder for "any string". So if a property is called `Alice` it will have one type but a property called `bob` will have a different value.

Comment: It should be fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512) when it gets included in a release. In the meantime, I don't see any solution to your problem.

Comment: However, trying it out in the [playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ts=4.4.0-pr-44512-32) there still is a conflict between your `type` property and  `t${string}`

Comment: Teneff- done
Altareos- very interesting! Glad to see that the TypeScript team already has a solution. Ah yeah, I wonder if there's anyway around that one. That's where there's an exception.

Comment: Whoops! Yes a typo. My mind somehow regressed to C

Comment: @FrankWeindel - huh, happens. Just asked you because sooner or later people will start bugging you about it :) As for the issue, yeah, you will have to wait until it's live, not much you can do now.

Comment: @FrankWeindel - btw, are `RefKey` and `PropKey` limited in what they can actually hold? I mean, do they hold arbitrary properties or a fixed set of those?

Comment: The capital letter keys are completely arbitrary. The lower case ones actually more defined, but have dependencies on the `type` and other lower case properties. The example I'm using is very contrived, but the actual use case makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @FrankWeindel hm, that's actually good. Can you share the exact constraints? Because currently, there may be a way around this: template literal types can be used in mapped types if there is a part of them that's not a union of all possible strings (`${string})`, but, for example, something like `${"o1"|"o2"|"o3"}`. I could draft up an answer if you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [`Alateros`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9365431/altareos) in the comments, since `typescript@4.4` you can use [index signatures for template literals](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512).

Though you still have to ensure `type` field must be required and may have the type that is not compatible with `lowercased` keys type. So you may write `Spec` type like that:

```ts
type Spec = {
  [K in RefKey | PropKey]: 'type' extends K 
      ? string 
      : K extends RefKey 
          ? SomeRefType 
          : K extends PropKey 
              ? SomePropType
              : never
} & {
  type: string
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2a0N)

Comment: Revisiting this now with the release of TS 4.4. Wish it was less complicated but it works! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I removed

```
type RefKey = `${UppercaseLetters}${string}`
type PropKey = `${LowercaseLetters}${string}`
```

and replaced with `UppercaseLetters` and `LowercaseLetters` types

[image]

Is it what are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry no. I'm trying to apply types based on the capitalization of the first letter of a key.

Comment: I just saw the example of the result ( output ). Can you show the input/types that you will get?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. The example I posted is both the input and  output. I'm trying to get TypeScript to treat that as a valid object.